# Create a function to filter two columns in R

Tags: r, loops, optimization

I have replicate this code with 4 different places and 4 different years.

```
df1 <- df %>% filter(Place == "Al" & year==2016)
rollingMean(df1, pollutant = "O", hours=8, new.name = "mean", data.thresh=75)
```

Sample of data:

```
Place       O    date_time               year
Al          23  2016-01-01 01:00:00     2016
Al          15  2016-01-01 02:00:00     2016
Al          18  2016-01-01 03:00:00     2016
Al          18  2016-01-01 04:00:00     2016
Al          20  2016-01-01 05:00:00     2016
Al          21  2016-01-01 06:00:00     2016
Ar          23  2016-01-01 01:00:00     2016
Ar          15  2016-01-01 02:00:00     2016
Ar          18  2016-01-01 03:00:00     2016
Ar          18  2016-01-01 04:00:00     2016
Ar          20  2016-01-01 05:00:00     2016
Ar          21  2016-01-01 06:00:00     2016
Ma          23  2016-01-01 01:00:00     2016
Ma          15  2016-01-01 02:00:00     2016
Ma          18  2016-01-01 03:00:00     2016
Ma          18  2016-01-01 04:00:00     2016
Ma          20  2016-01-01 05:00:00     2016
Ma          21  2016-01-01 06:00:00     2016
Ss          23  2016-01-01 01:00:00     2016
Ss          15  2016-01-01 02:00:00     2016
Ss          18  2016-01-01 03:00:00     2016
Ss          18  2016-01-01 04:00:00     2016
Ss          20  2016-01-01 05:00:00     2016
Ss          21  2016-01-01 06:00:00     2016
```

How can I optimize my code? I think that I need to loop or map but it is my first time doing this.

Comment: Do you need to run the code for every combination of place and year (16 iterations) or for each pair of place and year (4 iterations)? If the former, nested calls to lapply will work. If the latter, a single call to mapply will do the trick.

Comment: I need 16 iterations in combination of place and year, any ideas?? Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You can split the dataset for every unique value of `Place` and `Year` and use `map` to run  `rollingMean` function for each group and combine them into one dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

result <- df %>%
            group_split(Place, Year) %>%
            map_df(~rollingMean(.x, pollutant = "O", hours=8, 
                                new.name = "mean", data.thresh=75))
```